# Bracket syntax in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, syntax

I like to mess with coding every now and then as a hobby and I noticed an unfamiliar syntax in some of the Apple Developer documentation:

`newSectionsArray[index]`

I normally expect something like:

`[object method]`

Can anyone explain this to me?

Thanks!

Comment: Syntactic sugar for `[yourArray objectAtIndex:index]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called object subscripting, as explained [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)

Its syntactic sugar, as

```
newSectionsArray[index]
```

gets translated by the compiler to

```
[newSectionsArray objectAtIndexedSubscript:index];
```

`NSDictionary` implements subscripting too, so you can access an element in this fashion:

```
dictionary[@"key"]
```

---

The cool (and potentially dangerous) feature is that this is generalized, so you can even have it on your own classes.

You just need to implement a couple of methods

(for indexed access)

```
- (id)objectAtIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)idx;
- (void)setObject:(id)obj atIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)idx;
```

or (for keyed access)

```
- (id)objectForKeyedSubscript:(id)key;
- (void)setObject:(id)obj forKeyedSubscript:(id)idx;
```

and you they will be called whenever you use bracket notation on the instances of you custom class.

So you could end up coding a grid-based game and accessing the elements on the grid by

```
board[@"B42"]; // => [board objectForKeyedSubscript:@"B42"]
```

or moving a piece on the board by

```
board[@"C42"] = @"Troll"; => [board setObject:@"Troll" forKeyedSubscript:@"C42"];
```

Nice, but I wouldn't abuse of it.

Answer (score 1):

That's [literal syntax](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html), introduced in   Clang 3.4. You could however use the old syntax `[newSectionsArray objectAtIndex:index]`. it's the same thing.

Comment: Objective-C 2.0 is ages old and came with 10.5. But it's a bit of a strange versioning convention anyways, internally we are at version 4-532.2, so far far away from 2.0 (but I guess evolutionary changes don't sell that well)

Comment: @JustSid Sorry about that, I should have checked first.

Answer (score 0):

`newSectionsArray` is probably an array (i.e. a contigous block of multiple objects of the same type) and `index` an integer. `newSectionsArray[index]` gives you the object at position `index` (starting counting with 0).

Comment: `newSectionsArray` is in this case an `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` and can store whatever object type (`id`) (they do **not** have to be of same type) ;)